# JavaScript second function parameter magically gets a value

Tags: javascript, function

I am reading the JavaScript Guide, section about functions. I got the following code from there:

```
function map(f, a) {
    var result = [], i;

    for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
        result[i] = f(a[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 5, 10];
var cube = numbers.map(function(x) {
    return x * x * x;
});

console.log(cube);
```

Result: `(5) [0, 1, 8, 125, 1000]`

My question is how does the second param `a`, in `map(f, a)` even get a value when called in `numbers.map`? I only see one param being passed and that is the anonymous function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: `numbers.map()` is the builtin `map` function, try using the one you wrote by writing `var cube = map(x => x * x * x, numbers)`

Comment: `map(f, a)` is never called.

Comment: you are using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Well the guide is quite confusing then... I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete, or at least different from the guide at the source page:

```
function map(f, a) {
  var result = []; 
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++)
    result[i] = f(a[i]);
  return result;
}

var f = function(x) {
  return x * x * x; 
}

var numbers = [0,1, 2, 5,10];
var cube = map(f, numbers);
console.log(cube);
```

Comment: it is a wiki and if you look at this revision his code is outdated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions$revision/1312237

Comment: You are right, @RobertRocha. Honestly, I didn't look into the revision history, prior to posting it. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the `Array` prototype. You can call your own `map`function by calling:

`map(yourFunc, numbers);`